# Transform each item in a JSON array to a JSON object

Tags: bash, json, jq

I need to transform this simple JSON array:

```
["169","19","33"]
```

to a more complicated JSON object for each item, like:

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "groupid": 169
    },
    {
      "groupid": 19
    },
    {
      "groupid": 33
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently, I do this using tools not designed for JSON, like sed, awk & whatever Unix tool — it’s dirty for that — and I fail to use JQ.

Is it possible to use a more elegant solution to transform a JSON array to a JSON object with JQ?

Answer (score 3):

This `jq` should do the trick:

```
jq '{groups: [ .[] | {groupid: .} ]}'
```

Comment: That works, thank you very much!